# List all the leaderboards in Google play game services

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

In the documentation the code snippet to display leaderboard is

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

This goes into the given leaderboard with LEADERBOARD_ID

My game has severel leaderboards and what I want to do is display a list of them so that user can select a specific leaderboard.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to use the default UI, you can use this:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(getApiClient()), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

Comment: The request code REQUEST_LEADERBOARD is an arbitrary integer that you define by yourself.

Comment: It is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the new way of doing it:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)!!)
                    .allLeaderboardsIntent
                    .addOnSuccessListener { intent ->
                        startActivityForResult(
                            intent,
                            RC_LEADERBOARD_UI
                        )
                    }

companion object{
    private const val RC_LEADERBOARD_UI = 9004
}
```